# Ansible: how to get all ptag from dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ansible

One of the ansible task has following output in dictionary. I want to print all ptag from below. How to access these?

```
ok: [SWITCH] => 
  msg:
    changed: false
    failed: false
    stdout:
    - TABLE_ctx:
        ROW_ctx:
        - cname: default
          ptag: UNDERLAY
          rid: 1.1.1.1
        - cname: default
          ptag: TEST1
          rid: 1.1.1.1
        - cname: default
          ptag: TEST2
          rid: 1.1.1.1
    stdout_lines:
    - TABLE_ctx:
        ROW_ctx:
        - cname: default
          ptag: UNDERLAY
          rid: 1.1.1.1
        - cname: default
          ptag: TEST1
          rid: 1.1.1.1
        - cname: default
          ptag: TEST2
          rid: 1.1.1.1
```

I did "OSPF_process_output.stdout_lines[0][0].ptag" but it doesn't print all available ptag from this dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```yaml
ptags: "{{ stdout|json_query('[].TABLE_ctx.ROW_ctx[].ptag') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ptags:
  - UNDERLAY
  - TEST1
  - TEST2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    stdout:
    - TABLE_ctx:
        ROW_ctx:
        - cname: default
          ptag: UNDERLAY
          rid: 1.1.1.1
        - cname: default
          ptag: TEST1
          rid: 1.1.1.1
        - cname: default
          ptag: TEST2
          rid: 1.1.1.1

    ptags: "{{ stdout|json_query('[].TABLE_ctx.ROW_ctx[].ptag') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ptags
```

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre]. Delete this comment. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and the section `What are comments for, and when shouldn't I comment?` in particular.

Comment: I am not clear with your statement. I have  "{{ process_output.stdout[0].TABLE_ctx.ROW_ctx[].ptag }}" and it throws error. can you help me with correct syntex?